# VBA - Application-defined error with Dir()

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having issues with the [Dir()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dir-function) function in Excel VBA. When I run the below code, the code repeats as expected until there are no more files that match my condition. Once the `Dir()` call should run out of files to return I get a `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined` error. I've tried all the other answers I could find that even remotely seemed like they applied to my situation.

```
Dim dataIter As Range
Dim outputIter As Range
Dim fileName As String
Dim wkbk As Workbook

fileName = Dir(path & "\" & "*.xlsm")
Do While Len(fileName) > 0
    Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(path & "\" & fileName)
    Set dataIter = wkbk.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
    Do While dataIter.Address <> wkbk.Sheets(1).Range("TITLE").Address
        If dataIter.Value <> "" Then
            'Extract the data I need
            Set outputIter = outputIter.Offset(1)
        End If
        Set dataIter = dataIter.Offset(1)
    Loop
    wkbk.Close False
    fileName = Dir() 'Fails here
Loop
```

Valid assumptions:

1. All needed sheets are the first in each workbook
2. All sheets have a properly placed "TITLE" named range

What could be causing this and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick fix using some error handling, since your code runs as expected until the end.

```
Sub test()

    Dim dataIter As Range
    Dim outputIter As Range
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim wkbk As Workbook

    fileName = Dir(path & "\" & "*.xlsm")
    Do While Len(fileName) > 0
        Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(path & "\" & fileName)
        Set dataIter = wkbk.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        Do While dataIter.Address <> wkbk.Sheets(1).Range("TITLE").Address
            If dataIter.Value <> "" Then
                'Extract the data I need
                Set outputIter = outputIter.Offset(1)
            End If
            Set dataIter = dataIter.Offset(1)
        Loop
        wkbk.Close False
        On Error GoTo ErrHandler
        fileName = Dir() 'Fails here
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop

    ' Any Remaining code

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        fileName = vbNullString
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Any idea why Dir is throwing this error?

Comment: Because at the end there is no Dir(). You already went through all of them therefore Dir() doesn’t exist.